# Regex Fails when space is removed in grok debugger

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I'm trying to extract date from a log file entry:

```
 ......
 Date is:2015-06-09
 ........
```

using grok debugger for logstash.

The regex I'm using is `(?<=Date is:)[0-9\-]*\s?`
This regex works on [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/) but there aren't any matches in grok debugger.

Interestingly, if I add a space after `:` in both regex and file entry, the grok debugger gives correct results.

Comment: Did you mean `(?<=Date is:)\s?[0-9\-]*` ?

Comment: why it's not `^Date is\:(.*)$` or `^Date is\:(\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d)$` ?

Comment: I'm trying to match the token after "Date is:" part.

Comment: Is the colon `:` a special character in groc? Otherwise, try and just match `:[0-9]`. Does that work?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Actually no, but that change resolved the issue..thanks! :D

Comment: Its better to know why something doesn't work than to guess the rest of your life.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
((?<=Date is:)[\d\-]+\s?)|((?<=Date is: )[\d\-]+\s?)
```

First I added + instead of * as there is at least one date. One side of the regex checks for a Date is: with no space following the colon, the other side has a space after the colon then the date.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this regex is doing?